# How to authenticate an app instead of an user with django rest framework?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, token

By default, TokenAuthentication creates one token for each user (User access tokens), what makes sense for an API accessed only by end users.

But to integrate with other applications, would be more suitable to authenticate the application itself (App access tokens), instead of to make the application access the API on behalf of a given user.

My question is how to achieve that with Django rest framework. Should I extend the tokens model to add a FK to the applications table or there is an "easy" way? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem problem properly Instead of per user a `token` you would like to have per device ( app ) an authentication token. There are some well used third party app's like [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) or [jwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) provide that. No need to do this manually.

Though i prefer django-rest-knox as it has delete all token facility. Which is very useful in case of lost or compromise device.